# Save the Value of 'Set Variable Activity' in Json file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I have value in Json format. I need to save this Value in Json file. I tried Copy activity by using additional column but I am getting this error "Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type". Is there any other way to save the value in Json file?

Comment: Please show us your json structure and more details. Or you can try to use the json() function to convert the string to json format.

Comment: Hi @Merry, Could you please show us more details about what you have tried.